# can I make zsh filename completion work like Vim?

Tags: vim, zsh, autocomplete, globbing

I use `setopt menu_complete` so that I can hit TAB repeatedly to get different filename completions in zsh.  However, I would also like to be able to type:

`ls ~/*.txt<TAB>`

and then use TAB to cycle through all the files that end with `.txt` in my home directory.  I do *not* want all matches to be inserted on the command line at once!

(I tried reading the relevant zsh man pages, but I think it could easily take me a week of reading just to figure out *whether* this is possible and perhaps another week to figure out *how*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `GLOB_COMPLETE` option (see [zshoptions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/zshoptions.1.html)). (By the way, this [zsh reference card](http://www.bash2zsh.com/zsh_refcard/refcard.pdf) is quite useful.)

Comment: _Perfect!!_  Thanks!  I'm sure the reference card will come in handy.  Somehow, I'm not at all surprised by the reference "card" being 14 pages long. :)